# How do you add a title to HTML5 time element for screen readers?

Tags: html, timestamp, screen-readers

I have two `time` elements indicating a start time and an end time for some TV listings. The design doesn't call for any titles for these times, as on screen they appear very self explanatory. However, I'd like to add something for screen readers, perhaps an attribute of some kind? Or perhaps I create a title but hide it with CSS?

What is the best way to handle this?

```
<time datetime="{{ start_time }}">{{ start_time|time:"H:i" }}</time> -
<time datetime="{{ end_time }}">{{ end_time|time:"H:i" }}</time>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put them in a `<dl>`, and hide the `<dt>`s from non-screenreaders.

e.g., HTML:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Start time</dt>
    <dd><time datetime="{{ start_time }}">{{ start_time|time:"H:i" }}</time></dd>

    <dt>End time</dt>
    <dd><time datetime="{{ end_time }}">{{ end_time|time:"H:i" }}</time></dd>
</dl>
```

CSS (from [HTML5 Boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/) `.visuallyhidden`)

```
/*
 * Hide only visually, but have it available for screenreaders: h5bp.com/v
 */

dt {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}

dd {
    display: inline; 
}

dt:first-child + dd::after {
    content: ' \2013 '
}
```

update: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PMfSL/), `dd` style, and en-dash instead of hyphen